# Connection to gmail with imap error

Tags: php, ssl, gmail, port, imap

I am trying to make a mail appliction in php with imap and gmail. I am using a free hosting site, http://powrhost.com/, and imap, ssl, and all the other stuff are installed on it. My login code is:

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = '*************@gmail.com';
$password = '**************';

/* try to connect */
 $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .   imap_last_error());
```

I know that everything is okay except I don't know if my host allows port 993. Is there a better free hosting that it will work or is my code wrong? BTW, no shell access. The error is: could not stream imap connection: timeout

Comment: If you have shell access to the server this is working on, try telnetting to gmail's port 993 and see if that connects/times out/connection refused.

Comment: The value you give to `$hostname` is not a hostname … but the first argument to `imap_open` isn't supposed to be one. Please use saner variable names. Until I dug deeper, it looked like it wasn't working because your hostname was horribly broken.

Comment: @xna_developer_group have you resolved this issue, I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = $imap_user;
$password = $imap_password;
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password);//Open Mailbox
```

To Access any other mailbox like Archive you just Change INBOX to Archive or what ever folder name is and i think this folder names are case sensitive.